# An interesting bug with ORDER BY FIELD

Tags: mysql

Version of MySQL: **5.0**.

**The query without whitespace (look at FIELD statement):**

[image]

**The query with whitespace (look at FIELD statement):**

[image]

Comment: Thats not a bug thats how it is you can not have a function name like `myfunction ()` it should be `myfunction()` no space before `()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is neither a bug nor version dependend.

You can't put a space between a function name and the paretheses.

```
function_name (...)
             ^-------------NO!
```